# Why could not connect to Homey (ws://172.17.0.1:30000)?

Tags: homey

I've created, validated and published my app by homey cli.

In 'Developer Tools', the app's state is 'Processing failed'.

When I try 'homey app run', got error as below:

```
hook@win10-pc05:/mnt/d/code/homey/com.alfred-iot$ homey app run
✓ Pre-processing app...
Added Driver `smart-lock`
✓ Validating app...
✓ Homey App validated successfully against level `debug`
✓ Creating session...
✓ Preparing Environment Variables...
 — Homey.env (env.json)
   — CLIENT_SECRET=Homey...D5ytl
   — CLIENT_ID=D1f4L...tp04O
   — WEBHOOK_ID=61c02...1ad57
   — WEBHOOK_SECRET=6e06c...51ab5
✓ Started Local HTTP Server at http://0.0.0.0:30000
✓ Connecting to Homey...
✓ Connected to Homey
✓ Starting app...
✓ Started app
✓ Debugger running at 0.0.0.0:9229. Open `about://inspect` in Google Chrome and select the target.
✓ Starting `com.alfred-iot`, press CTRL+C to quit
Debugger listening on ws://0.0.0.0:9229/2af4135e-1fd0-402d-ac03-6a4cc889063f
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Could not connect to Homey (ws://172.17.0.1:30000).
```

Answer (score 0):

You can click the red processing failed icon to see the error, it says that you are trying to publish your app for Homey Cloud but you are not a verified developer.

Are you setting `"platforms": ["cloud"]` in your `app.json` manifest? If so you should be able to publish your app after removing it.

Otherwise, could you share your `app.json` or a link to the source code of your app?